# Bad notification posted when using custom view in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, notifications, android-custom-view

When I use a custom view in my notification's layout, I get crash `RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package ...`. Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<com.myapp.views.FontedTextView
    android:id="@+id/idas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If I use `TextView` instead of `com.myapp.views.FontedTextView`, it works fine. Note, that in normal activity, `com.myapp.views.FontedTextView` works perfectly.

```
public class FontedTextView extends TextView
{
public FontedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        if(isInEditMode()) return;
        createFont();
}

public FontedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if(isInEditMode()) return;
        createFont();
}

public FontedTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        if(isInEditMode()) return;
        createFont();
}

public void createFont()
{
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "Lato-Regular.ttf");
    setTypeface(font);
}
}
```

instantiation:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    RemoteViews remoteviews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.remotecontrol_notification);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContent(remoteviews)
    .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0));

    notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());
```

Comment: Lets see how you instantiate it in code.  Is it crashing when it gets created

Comment: not possible at all, simple logic: notification using RemoteViews, [*which do not support every kind of layout or view widget*](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout)

Comment: @Selvin so how do I workaround it? any hacks?

Comment: FSM save us!!!  google  + remoteviews setTypeface android

Comment: why the hell did they made crappy sh*t RemoteViews instead of using normal View class...

Comment: because it is not your app that is showing the notification ... i'm not sure it may be a launcher app, android's shell or somthing like this ... **for security reasons it doesn't like to run your code** (you can put there any code and it would be run with launcher/shell app credentials) ... it trust only some of the normal android widgets